# How do you perform actions only to things that are in an ArrayList in Java?

Tags: java, arraylist, minecraft

This is a re-write of my previous question as I was told that it is too long.

```
if(/*This is where I need something*/)
{
    mc.thePlayer.swingItem();
    mc.playerController.attackEntity(mc.thePlayer, e);
    delay = 0;
    break;
}
```

This is part of the code for a KillAura in Minecraft. I am trying to make it so that it does not target people in a friends list that I made. That list is an ArrayList called "friendslist" in a file called Variables.java. I would be really grateful if someone could explain to me how I make it not target people in my friendslist. Please keep it nice and simple as I am relatively new to java.

Thanks in advance.

Matt

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15321750/how-to-perform-an-action-to-only-items-that-are-in-an-arraylist-in-java

Comment: There is no comma `;` between your `if-statement` and your bracket `{` in `Java`.

Answer (score 1):

An `ArrayList` object has a method called `contains`. Using this method you can test if an object is part of a collection. Read the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html).

**Worked Example**

```
ArrayList<People> people = new ArrayList<People>();
// Define the collection.
People p = new People("Dave");
// Create a new test object.
people.add(p);
// Add the object to the collection.
if(people.contains(p))
{
    // Will print out, because P exists within the people collection.
    System.out.println("Object exists in the collection");
}
```

### Refinement on my Original Answer

As suggested in the comments, given this is a comparison algorithm for a game, you might want to optimize this a little more. With that in mind, I thought of using a [HashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html).

**Example of a HashMap**

```
HashMap<String, Person> friends = new HashMap<String, Person>();
// Create the HashMap object.
Person p = new Person("Dave");
// Create a test object, with the name "Dave".
String key = p.getName();
// Get a key. In this case, the object's name.
friends.put(key, p);
// Add the person to the collection.
```

With this code, you now have a person in your HashMap collection. Now, when someone walks into your 'attack aura', you can simply get that person's name, and check if a key exists in your HashMap. This is quick (O(1) complexity) and accurate, and best of all, you're comparing a custom value; not the same object. So the user can recycle their objects and still be stored in your Collection.

Hopefully this edit will help :)

Comment: Thanks for your help but is there any way that I can do this with any person I add to my friends list. I forgot to mention that I use a chat command. If it type in .add <Username> it adds them to my friends list. The string that it adds (the one that they typed) is called friend. Is there any way I can get it to not attack any friend I add?

Comment: I would recommend using a `Set` rather than a `List`, `Set`s have a guaranteed O(1) `contains` method, `List`s are likely to be O(n).

Comment: Agreed; I guess in terms of a game we need to take algorithmic complexity into account. I'll edit your answer in. @bobvader Do you want to get the person near you. Check to see if they exist inside your collection, and act accordingly. I'll alter my answer for you.

Comment: Thank you sooo much for trying to help Chris. I should probably change my original question to "very new to java" as I am very confused by the hash map thing. I will explain my set up and would be extremely thankful if you could help me adapt it for my setup. I have a file called Variables.java which creates what is currently an Array List and the string "friend" which is what I use to add the username that people type in to the list. There is another file called EntityClientPlayerMP.java which contains the chat command for adding people to the list.

Comment: Under that, it basically says "If that name is already there remove it but if it is not there, add it". My guess is I put the hash map creation in the Variables.java in the place of the ArrayList. The furthest I got was <String, Person>. I presume that the string should be the string "friend" from what the player types in but I am not entirely sure what to put under person and where to put the other bits.

Comment: The string would be, for example, the name of the friend. Something unique about the friend object that can be stored in a string. The Person is the actual friend.

Answer (score 0):

In order to find if an object is not in a list, use:

```
if (!friendslist.contains(otherPlayer))
```

where `friendslist` is your friends list and `otherPlayer` is a player to look if in your friends list or not.

You can read more about [lists](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html) and [arraylists](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)

Answer (score 0):

It is a little difficult to tell just what all the pieces are, but if friendslist is an array list containing the player object, and thePlayer is the one you are checking, then

```
if (!(friendslist.contains(mc.thePlayer)))
```